# node js array.push 'not' working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm sure making a silly mistake, but can't trace it. Have a simple script to read in a file of the form:

```
<option value="us">United States</option>
```

trying to create a new file of the form:

```
{"value":"us","name":"United States"}
```

The issue is `jsonC.push(c)` is not working and the array remains empty. The `console.log(c)` does print `json` representation, still the very next line `jsonC.push(c)` fails to have any effect on `jsonC` array and it remains empty.

Here is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

var src = 'country.txt';
var dest = 'country.json';

var re = /.+["](\w{2})["][>]([a-zA-Z ]+)[<][/].+/;
var jsonC = [];

readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(src), terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
    var match;
    if ((match = re.exec(line)) !== null) {
      var c = {};
      c.value = match[1];
      c.name = match[2];

      console.log(c); // prints fine
      jsonC.push(c); // not adding to the array
   }
});

console.log(jsonC); // prints []
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonC)); // prints []
```

This is a stand alone `node.js v4.2.6` script running on `Win 7`.

Comment: Have you ever heard about functional programming, asynchronous operations and so on? This is how it works indeed.

Comment: @skypjack, 15 years of java did it. :-( started on node a couple of weeks back. :-)

Comment: The problem is that the callback function is not executed immediately, not Array.push(). Add some prefixes to your console.log messages and note the order they are printed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are adding values to jsonC in an callback function. the `readline.createInterface(...).on(function() {` is a callback, and is not synchronous. So your program is just scheduling that function away, and then it does `console.log(jsonC)` and jsonC is still empty because the callback hasn't fired yet.

Try outputing the value in the callback, or using promises to know when the callback has finished.

Here is a working example using Promises:

```
function readFromFile() {
    var fsRead = Promise.defer();
    readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(src), terminal: false
    }).on('line', function(line) {
        var match;
        if ((match = re.exec(line)) !== null) {
          var c = {};
          c.value = match[1];
          c.name = match[2];
          jsonC.push(c);
          fsRead.resolve();
       }
    });
    return fsRead.promise();
}

readFromFile().then(function(result) {
    console.log(jsonC);
})
```